# Asyncio unit test shall fail when not all tasks are stopped at the end of the test

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-asyncio

How can i reach that the unit test fails if not all tasks are stopped until the end of the test?

I need this to test if the cleanup of a tested module is as expected.

Test Environment: Windows, python 3.9, aiounittest 1.4.0

The unit test **test_async_still_running** shows the following text at the end:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.004s
OK

Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name= ... =<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x04772130>()]>>
```

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
import aiounittest

class TestMissingAwait(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):
    async def some_delay(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def test_task_still_running(self):
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.some_delay())
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to test if additional tasks are pending at the end of the unit test.
The test can be done e.g. by the decorator (**check_pending_tasks** in the following solution).

An **PendingTaksError** will be raised if a task is pending to let the unit test to fail.

```
import os
import functools
import inspect
import asyncio
import aiounittest

# Enable additional checks + output in asyncio
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'

class PendingTaksError(Exception):
    pass

def check_pending_tasks(func):
    """
    Wrapper to check if all tasks are stopped at the end of the test
    """
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def decorate(self):
        """
        Raises a PendingTaksError if not all tasks have been finished
        """
        # Tasks of the test-runner are out of interrest
        unit_test_tasks = set(asyncio.all_tasks())
        result = await func(self) # Execute the test
        pending_tasks = set(asyncio.all_tasks()) - unit_test_tasks

        if pending_tasks:
            exc_text = ' Not all tasks are stopped correctly in the unit test "{}.{}"\n'
            exc_text = exc_text.format(type(self).__name__, func.__name__)
            exc_text += 'file={}\n'.format(inspect.getfile(self.__class__))
            exc_text += 'pending Tasks:\n'
            for task in pending_tasks:
                exc_text +=  '{}\n'.format(task)
            raise PendingTaksError(exc_text)
        return result

    return decorate

class TestMissingAwait(aiounittest.AsyncTestCase):

    async def some_delay(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    @check_pending_tasks
    async def test_task_still_running(self):
        my_task = asyncio.create_task(self.some_delay(), name='my_task')
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Comment: It will be better to use **asynctest.TestCase** instead of **aiounittest.AsyncTestCase**. Then you can decorate your test function with **@asynctest.fail_on(active_handles=True)** to check for unfinished tasks.